# Image does not show up in selectbox (Twitter Bootstrap plugin)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I am trying to create a select box that shows all Twitter Bootstrap Icons with its text. Therefore I am using the [Bootstrap-Select Plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/). One of the images shows up in the list, but the rest is somehow hidden.

[image]

What do I have to change in order to get the list of all listed icons with its text?

JS:

```
<script src="source/bootstrap_select/bootstrap-select.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('');
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option data-icon="icon-search">icon-search</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-envelope">icon-envelope</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-heart" selected="selected">icon-heart</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-star">icon-star</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-star-empty">icon-star-empty</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-user">icon-user</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-film">icon-film</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-th-large">icon-th-large</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-th">icon-th</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-th-list">icon-th-list</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-ok">icon-ok</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-remove">icon-remove</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-zoom-in">icon-zoom-in</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-zoom-out">icon-zoom-out</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-off">icon-off</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-signal">icon-signal</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-cog">icon-cog</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-trash">icon-trash</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-home">icon-home</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-file">icon-file</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-time">icon-time</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-road">icon-road</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-download-alt">icon-download-alt</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-download">icon-download</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-upload">icon-upload</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-inbox">icon-inbox</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-play-circle">icon-play-circle</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-repeat">icon-repeat</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-refresh">icon-refresh</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-list-alt">icon-list-alt</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-lock">icon-lock</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-flag">icon-flag</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-headphones">icon-headphones</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-glass">icon-glass</option>
    <option data-icon="icon-music">icon-music</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link href="source/bootstrap_select/bootstrap-select.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

was missing!